# "Cannot resolve symbol services" for `import com.mapbox.services.android`

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I wanted to use the class `LostLocationEngine` in the package `com.mapbox.services.android.location` [shown in this Mapbox documentation,](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/mapbox-java/libandroid-services/2.1.0/com/mapbox/services/android/location/LostLocationEngine.html) however I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'services'`. Is it something with my gradle?

Here are my repositories and dependencies, and let me know if you need any other information:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.2.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v8:0.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency to your build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.11.0'

  implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.8.0'
```

reference link https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/location-layer/